# List all groups of a user in one row as a multi-field

Tags: views, 9, group

I want to list all the users and groups they are member of in one table, one row per user.

I have a simple view that lists all users in the system. I added relation to group content membership and a "Parent group" field to the view.

I tried aggregation, but no luck.

Lets say we have 3 users (*user1*, *user2* and, *user3*) and 3 groups (*Interest1*, *Interest2*, and *Interest3*). *user1* is not a member of any group; *user2* is member of *Interest1*; *user3* is member of *Interest1* and *Interest2*.

What I want to see is the following.

| Users | Interests |
| --- | --- |
| user1 |  |
| user2 | Interest1 |
| user3 | Interest1, Interest2 |

What I get is instead this.

| Users | Interests |
| --- | --- |
| user1 |  |
| user2 | Interest1 |
| user3 | Interest1 |
| user3 | Interest2 |

I also don't see multiple configuration ("Multiple field settings") or something similar in the group field settings.

Comment: You need to aggregate the group field.

Comment: Hello, 
I already tried it. But that did not work. It still showed the two rows when I activated the aggregate function.

Comment: for now I solved using views_field_view with contextual filter

Comment: You need to clarify how the users are related to groups, what types of references are they, are users connected to groups directly, or indirectly through group content, what is a parent group, what field did you set the Aggregation to which option?